# Subclause with "wollen" and "ob"

Tags: grammar, translation

I'm trying to say

> "I'm making these videos because I want to see if I can improve."

I came up with this:

> Ich mache diese Videos, weil ich sehen wollen, ob ich verbessern kann.

I'm not very confident with subclauses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's just 2 small things wrong

wollen has to be declined: In this case the first person singular, which you can find in this declination table. Result: `(ich) will`

furthermore your use of verbessern requires reflexive usage:

> ob ich **mich** verbessern kann

final result:

> Ich mache diese Videos, weil ich sehen will, ob ich mich verbessern kann.

Answer (score 5):

The original string is not clear:

Either you want to say `"I'm making these videos because I want to see if I can improve myself."` would be `Ich mache diese Videos, weil ich sehen wollte, ob ich mich verbessern kann.`

In case you want to improve the videos, it would be something like: `Ich mache diese Videos, weil ich sehen wollte, ob ich die Videos [noch] verbessern kann.`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wouldn't it be "will" instead of "wollte"?

Comment: Hmmm... good question. I decided for "wollte", because the decission has been in past ... but to be honest, I cannot say whether its grammatically correct.